# Please help me to understand what is this code doing

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In this code below could you describe the elements of the code and what is occurring?

Please help me to understand what this is doing? I have to figure what this code is doing. I know it is JavaScript and has some alerts in the code. I would just need some help on what is occurring. Also it looks like a very simple code:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Jeeves</title > 

<script >   Javascript

var butler  = 
{
  disposition: "formal",   What is this doing?
  happy: true,
  
  shineShoes: function()
  {
    if(this.happy )
    {
      alert("I have shined your shoes"); 
    } 
    else
    {
      alert("You can shine your own shoes today"); What is this doing?
    }
  }
};


butler.happy = false;
butler.shineShoes();


alert(butler.disposition);
alert(butler.happy);


butler.disposition = "informal";
butler.happy = false;




var newButler = Object.create(butler);
newButler.disposition = "informal";   What is this doing?
newButler.shineShoes();
alert(newButler.disposition);


butler.accent = "british";
alert(butler.accent);


butler.ironShirts = function()
{
  alert("I will be ironing your shirts");
}

butler.ironShirts();

</script>
```

Comment: Please change your title to be more descriptive of the subject matter of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `butler` variable is an object, it has two properties: `disposition`, `happy` and one method: `shineShoes`

`disposition` property is defined as `"formal"` string,
`happy` property is defined as `true` boolean,
`shineShoes` method will test whether the butler's object (`this`) property `happy` is true or false. Both cases will generate an alert.

In the following 6 lines of code (excluding empty ones) you're just re-defining butler object's properties, calling `shineShoes` method and displaying some alters containing this object's properties.

Further below a new object `newButler` is created, this object is a copy of `butler` object which will become a "prototype". `newButler` will inherit all its prototype's existing and incoming properties and methods, but not viceversa. The last lines are a serie of tests that you can perform to get some education about javascript objects, prototypes and its inheritance topics.